# How to find the different variables of a column

Tags: pandas

Data set is below

```
no,store_id,revenue,profit,state,country,label
0,101,779183,281257,WD,India,1
1,101,144829,838451,WD,India,0
2,101,766465,757565,AL,Japan,-1
3,102,766465,757565,AL,Japan,-1
```

- the different labels are `-1,0,1`
- the different countries are `India, Japan`
- How to distinct count of each country also like 
  `India = 2`, `Japan = 2`

Comment: `df['column'].value_counts()` or `df['column'].unique()`.

Comment: @MayankPorwal added one more suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = df.groupby(by=['country']).size()
print(df)

country
India    2
Japan    2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unique` method to do so. For any column, `df.column.unique()` gives all the unique values. For counts, you can use `df.column.value_counts()`.

Comment: How to check, how to get the count of each country like ``Japan = 4`, India =2`

Comment: How is count for Japan=4?

Comment: df['country'].value_counts()